# Marekto, Velocity Scripting for Emails and Soft Bounce

Tags: java, email, velocity, bounce, marketo

The below velocity script in marketo has a 50% soft bounce rate for and are not able to ever successfully send the following reason:

"Velocity transform failed: ; The nested exception is: org.apache.velocity.exception.MethodInvocationException: Invocation of method 'parseInt' in class java.lang.Integer threw exception java.lang.NumberFormatException: null at 518-SGV-772:250:1:static[line 145, column 30] "

Does anyone know how to modify script to solve soft bounce issue?

```
 #foreach ($campaign_c in $campaign_cList)
   #set( $today = $date.get('yyyyMMdd'))
   #set( $strEnddate = $ams_campaign_c.enddate.replace("-",""))
   #set( $val = 1 )
   #set( $intEnddate = $val.parseInt($strEnddate))
   #set( $intToday = $val.parseInt($today))
   #set( $isFuture = "FALSE")
   #if ( $intEnddate > $intToday )
       #set( $isFuture = "TRUE")
#end
#if ( ( $campaign_c.isoutofbudget == 1)
    and ($campaign_c.marketplaceid == 1) 
    and ($campaign_c.product != "SP")
    and ($isFuture == "TRUE" ))
<tr>
<td>$campaign_c.campaignname</td>
   <td>$campaign_c.brandname</td>
   <td>$date.format('MM/dd/yyyy', ${convert.parseDate($campaign_c.enddate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')})</td>
</tr>
#end
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it's happening somewhere in your loop during this line

```
#set( $intEnddate = $val.parseInt($strEnddate))
```

Without know what type of data is coming through in $ams_campaign_c.enddate it's difficult to say what the exact cause is going to be, but I would guess that the data here is not necessarily leaving you with a string of integer characters.